# Color axis labels for pandas plotting on dark theme notebook

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Jupyter Lab to plot some data using pandas plotting like this:

```
df.plot()
```

The trouble is that while the plot area is colored white, the axis labels are in black which is very difficult to see with a dark jupyter lab theme. Is there a way to make the entire plot background white so that I can see the labels. I have put an example image below.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set a different style for `matplotlib` to use, which should override the default color choices.  `pandas` uses `matplotlib` as its plotting library.  You can see the available options on the [documentation page](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html) or via:

```
from matplotlib import style

style.available
# returns:
['bmh',
 'classic',
 'dark_background',
 'fast',
 'fivethirtyeight',
 'ggplot',
 'grayscale',
 'seaborn-bright',
 'seaborn-colorblind',
 'seaborn-dark-palette',
 'seaborn-dark',
 'seaborn-darkgrid',
 'seaborn-deep',
 'seaborn-muted',
 'seaborn-notebook',
 'seaborn-paper',
 'seaborn-pastel',
 'seaborn-poster',
 'seaborn-talk',
 'seaborn-ticks',
 'seaborn-white',
 'seaborn-whitegrid',
 'seaborn',
 'Solarize_Light2',
 '_classic_test']
```

Since you are using a dark themed notebook, try a dark themed plot:

```
style.use('dark_background')
```